# Ternary Operator

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Is it possible to change this:

```java
if (string != null) {
    callFunction(parameters);
} else {
    // Intentionally left blank
}
```

to a ternary operator?

Comment: An if statement in Java does not have a return type; to recode it using a ternary operator then you would have to add one.

Comment: The short answer is "no", why would you?

Comment: There isn't much point in the ternary operator if you do nothing when the condition is false.

Comment: I think trying to add a ternary operator to this logic is pointless. It is not going to make your code more readable or maintainable IMO.

Answer (score 62):

Well, the `ternary operator` in Java acts like this...

```
return_value = (true-false condition) ? (if true expression) : (if false expression);
```

**...Another way of looking at it...**

```
return_value = (true-false condition) 
             ? (if true expression) 
             : (if false expression);
```

---

You question is kind of vague and we have to assume here.

- If **(and only if)** `callFunction(...)` declares a `non-void` return value (`Object`, `String`, `int`, `double`, etc..) *- it seems like it does not do that via your code -* then you could do this...

  ```
  return_value = (string != null) 
               ? (callFunction(...)) 
               : (null);
  ```
- If `callFunction(...)` does not return a value, then you **cannot** use the ternary operator! Simple as that. You will be using something that you don't need.

  - Please post more code to clear up any issues

---

Nonetheless, **ternary operator should represent alternative assignments only!!** Your code does not seem to do that, so you should not be doing that.

This is how they should work...

```
if (obj != null) {            // If-else statement

    retVal = obj.getValue();  // One alternative assignment for retVal

} else {

    retVal = "";              // Second alternative assignment for retVale

}
```

This can be converted to...

```
retVal = (obj != null)
       ? (obj.getValue())
       : ("");
```

---

**Since it seems like you *might* be trying to just refactor this code to be a one-liner, I have added the following**

Also, if your false-clause is truely empty, then you can do this...

```
if (string != null) {

    callFunction(...);

} // Take note that there is not false clause because it isn't needed
```

OR

```
if (string != null) callFunction(...);  // One-liner
```

Comment: You should not use the word “statement” for things that are actually an “expression”. These two words have a precise meaning in the Java language.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can with keeping same `null` in `else` block.

```
String result = str !=null ?  callFunction(parameters) : null;
```

Make sure that `callFunction(parameters)`  return a `String`.

Comment: You are assuming here that callFunction returns an object.  You will hit problems if it was void, or a primitive return type.

Comment: @ChrisK That is very obvious to return a String. Added a note anyway.

Comment: @sureshatta, it is only obvious to people who already know.  It will improve the answer to make it explicit.

Comment: @ChrisK Yes. Yes. I already added a note while you are commenting.

Comment: I dont think its possible as there is no String return type for callFunction and even if it has he will have to make sure that it doesn't return a null value. As in that case the true and false result is same and it will be hard to understand whether copndition was true or false.

Comment: @Niru `I dont think its possible as there is no String return type for callFunction` .. Who  told that no String return type ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ: who told you that it has a `String` return type? The code of the question does not allow such a conclusion.

Comment: If anything is obvious from the question, then it is that there is *no* return value because OP's code makes no attempt to capture it. It is the most obvious piece of code which can be described as "do *this* only if *that* is not null". *Doing* things is what `if` is for; *calculating values* is what a ternary operator is for.

Answer (score 3):

The ternary operator can be used to combine two *expressions* but an empty *statement* is not an expression.

A method invocation can be used as an expression if the method returns a value (read: is not declared `void`) and it could be used together with a dummy constant `null` to form a ternary operator but the result would be again an expression which is not allowed in places where a *statement* is required, in other words, it can not replace an `if` statement.

By adding another construct taking an expression and imposing no additional side effect you can construct a complete replacement. E.g. by declaring and assigning a new, otherwise unused, local variable you get:

```
Object dummy=condition? callFunction(parameters): null;
```

But there is no benefit over simply saying `if(condition) callFunction(parameters);`. It might even add unnecessary overhead as it will perform auto-boxing if the return value is a primitive type.

With Java 8 there is a solution to the puzzle that works even for `void` methods:

```
((Runnable)(condition? ()->callFunction(parameters): ()->{})).run();
```

but it still has no advantage over simply using `if`.

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible if your method `callFunction()` has a return type. Then, you could do it like *SURESH ATTA* wrote in his answer:

```
String result = str!=null ? callFunction(str) : null;
```

Or with any other type for result or any other arguments. If you want to call a method in the `else`-Statement too, this one needs to have the same return type as the one in your `if`-statement.

If your method doesn't have a return type / the return type of `callFunction()` is `void`, it is not possible to change your `if`-`else`-statement into a ternary operator.