# Alternate way for nested ifs using Boolean in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, collections, java-8, switch-statement

I have below block of code

```
if(Objects.nonNull(isMine)) {
    if (isMine) {
             this.books= // gets it from the database;
    } else  {
            this. books= // gets it from the database
    }

 } else {
     this. books = // gets it from the database
 }
```

isMine -  is a Boolean object
I tried with switch case by converting isMine to a string as below

```
 String.valueOf(isMine)
```

But didn't work .Suggest a  better and faster way to implement above code in java.

Comment: What do you mean by faster? It looks fine. You could make a bit easier to read by inverting the null check (see Flown's answer), but other than that...

Comment: you can remove first if statement as boolean cannot be null.

Comment: @Sam a `Boolean` (empasis uppercase) can be null

Comment: @Sam since there is a boxed version, you can.

Comment: @Sam, it can if he's using the wrapper object.

Comment: correct Matt. I was assuming it as wrapper.

Comment: What do you mean with “But didn't work”? Be more specific. I don’t see any reason why `String.valueOf(isMine)` shouldn’t work. Besides that, why do you have a conditional at all? In all cases, you are doing the same `this. books= // gets it from the database`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Optional` in this case:

```
Boolean isMine = null;
String str = "";
Optional<Boolean> optional = Optional.ofNullable(isMine);
str = optional.map(i -> i ? "a" : "b").orElse("c");
System.out.println(str);
```

So it will be something like:

```
this.books = optional.map(i -> i ? valForTrue : valForFalse).orElse(valForNull);
```

Comment: `List<Book> books = Optional.ofNullable(isMine).map(v -> v ? dbCallX() : dbCallY()).orElseGet(() -> dbCallZ());`

Answer (score 6):

You can flatten your if-else statement by using else if:

```
if(isMine == null) {
  books = allList;
} else if(isMine) {
  books = myList;
} else {
  books = notMyList;
}
```

Another approach would be to sperate the checks into methods:

```
  public List<Book> getBookList(Boolean isMine) {
    return isMine == null ? allList : getBookList(isMine.booleanValue());
  }

  public List<Book> getBookList(boolean isMine) {
    return isMine ? myList : notMyList;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`this.books = isMine != null ? (isMine ? this.myList : this.notMyList) : this.allList`;

Using [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java) inside of ternary operator e.g.

Comment: The saved lines of code here are really not worth the worsened readability.

Answer (score 0):

Do not even think about performance in your case, that's tiny.

Your current way looks good. And you have an answer with  flatten way and nested ternary too.

If you still want to learn how to use switch in this case (*please do not put this code in production.* posting for showing you a way)

Correct way to achieve using `String.valueOf(isMine)` is

```
switch ( String.valueOf(isMine) ) {
        case "null":
            //TODO
            break;
        case "true":
            //TODO
            break;
        case "false":
            //TODO
        break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With pattern matching provided by vavr.io it can get very clean:

```
List<Books> output = Match(input).of(
        Case($(true), dbCallX()),
        Case($(false), dbCallY()),
        Case($(), dbCallZ()));
```