# Java - Recursive solving with check number

Tags: java, recursion

I'm stuck with an exercise involving recursion

***The question:***

Write a recursive function which returns an integer, the "check digit". This check digit is computed by calculating the sum of all digits from the passed-in integer. However, if the result is greater than or equal to 10 (i.e., more than a single digit), then the calculation should be performed again using the result as input. And thus until the final number returned will be a single digit; this digit is the "check digit".

***An Example:***

With the number 869419 ----> 8+6+9+4+1+9 = 37 --> 3+7 = 10 -> 1.

***The Closest Solution I've reached : ***

```
public static int Bik (int n) {
    int sum=0;
    if (n/10 == 1 || n==1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        if (n%10 != 0) {
            return Bik((n/10) + (n%10));
        }
        return (n);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Bik(1892));
}
```

Comment: you should paste code as text, and not as a picture. also, SO is not here to give you code but answer a specific question

Comment: Type the code here, in the question.

Comment: Take a really small example, such as 12, and singlestep the whole program in a debugger.

Comment: Btw, the non-recursive solution is `n % 9 == 1`.

Comment: @Henry if you understand what Elioz is asking then please translate it into English for the rest of us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickParker Sry dude, I'm not an English native speaker.

Comment: It's unclear what the return value should be. If the answer would always be 1, then you could return 1 right away without doing any work

Comment: What would you expect the check-digit to be for the number you provide in your test (`1892`) - I get `18928`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I did wrote an example of a number in the question

Comment: After your edit your requirements are now clearer. I have now also edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one problem on line 1 of your Bik Method:

Every time you call it the variable `sum` is defined to `0` so it never changes. Also in your code you never actually sum the value from the previous iteration. The solution I can come with is to pass another parameter with the sum of the previous iteration:

```
public static int Bik (int n, int sum) {
    // You get the value of the last digit and sum it to your total
    sum += n%10;
    // This validation is to know if there is only 1 digit left  
    if (n>9) 
        // The required recursion
        return Bik(n/10, sum); 
    //In case the sum is higher than 9 the recursion is called again, otherwise it returns the sum
    return sum>9 ? Bik(sum, 0) : sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Bik(1892, 0));
}
```

Please note this solution also works for numbers in which the recursion has to run more than once like 189235. Also I used a ternary operator. You can learn more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java) but if you don't like it you can use a regular `if` statement as well

Comment: While can't be used in recursion

Comment: Updated the solution

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check if the input is bigger than 10 otherwise just return the input.

```
if(input < 10) { //no computation required return input
     return input;
}
```

Then if input is bigger than 10. You need to obtain every digits composing the input. To obtain a digit just make a modulo 10 `input%10`. This will give you the last digit. Then divide the input by 10 and redo the operation to obtain the next digit. Repeat this until input is lower than 10. Here you've obtain all the digit

```
while(input > 9) { // until input is lower than 10
    int newDigit = input % 10; //find a digit
    digits.add(Integer.valueOf(newDigit);  //ass it to a list
    input /= 10;  //reduce input
}
digits.add(Integer.valueOf(input)); //add the last input digit
```

After you have to sum all the element in the list to obtain your result

```
for(Integer i : digits) { //sum all digits
    result += i;
}
```

Finally return the computation of this result. By doing this you use recursivity, if result is lower than 10 it will be return, if it's greater it will be computed again.

```
return compute(result); // return the computed result
```

The total of these steps should give you something like :

```
public int compute(int input) {
    if(input < 10) { //no computation required return input
         return input;
    } else {
        List<Integer> digits = new ArrayList<Interger>(); //will contains the digit composing input
        int inComputationInt = input; //a copy of input that will be modified
        int result = 0; //the resulting sum of digit

        while(inComputationInt > 9) { //obtain every digit in input
            int newDigit = inComputation % 10;
            digits.add(Integer.valueOf(newDigit));
            inComputation /= 10;
        }
        digits.add(Integer.valueOf(inComputation);

        for(Integer i : digits) { //sum all digits
            result += i;
        }

        return compute(result); // return the computation of result
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the long solution and the time for trying to resolve this question, Secondly, unfortunately, the solution has to be recursive.

Comment: @EliozKhan It was a typo mistakes ;-). Check my edit, this solution is recursive

Answer (score 0):

After your edit - now much clearer.

```
int checkDigit(int n) {
    // Any single-digit is the check digit.
    if (n < 10) return n;
    // More than one digit - add them up.
    String digits = Integer.toString(n);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++) {
        sum += digits.charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    // Check that sum.
    return checkDigit(sum);
}

private void test(int n) {
    System.out.println("Check difgit for "+n+" = "+checkDigit(n));
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    int[] tests = {86941,869419,189,1892};
    for(int n: tests) {
        test(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm, a recursive function with a `for` loop. if we're really doing recursion here, then it should be a recursive helper call instead of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int digitSum(int n) {
 if(n < 10) return n;
 return n % 10 + digitSum(n / 10);
}
```

First of all you need a base case and in this case it's the number you provide and if it's less than 10 just return the given number.

The second return statement takes the rightmost digit (modulo calculation n % 10) and saves it to its stack, and then call the method again but with (n / 10) and this calculation removes the rightmost digit because you already used it in the modulo calculation so you don´t need it anymore. Pass the new number into the method and repeat this process until your number is less than 10.

Hopes this clarifies a little bit.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

include this method to your code, pass the digit to digitSum

```
static int digitSum(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    // Loop to do sum while
    // sum is not less than
    // or equal to 9
    while (n > 0 || sum > 9) 
    {
        if (n == 0) {
            n = sum;
            sum = 0;
        }
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: But the exercise should use recursion.

Comment: @Charan I was looking to sum the N (int variable) until the sum of the digit of the numbers equals 1. and it has to be recursive

Comment: @EliozKhan then the answer would always be 1, so you could return 1 right away without doing any work...

Comment: `9%9` equals 0.

Comment: @EliozKhan that's what the code is doing it adds the digits of the number(n) you entered until the sum is single digited, if I was wrong help me where i did wrong