# Recursion problem - is this solution correct, and is there a simpler one?

Tags: java, recursion

I am new to recursion and I found the following Java problem: 
 Write a function that gets an integer n, and prints the numbers 1!,2!,3!,...,n!. 
 Here is what I did and I would like to know if this is the simplest solution (I am not sure because I used "for" loop to do it).

```java
public static void Print(int n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    System.out.print("1");
  } else {
    int temp = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n, i++) {
      temp = temp * i;
    }
    Print(n-1);
    System.out.print(temp);
  }
}
```

By the way, the previous exercise was to write a function that gets an integer n and returns n!, using recursion. Do you think I need to use it here and print it instead of calculating temp (n!) and print it?
Thanks!

Comment: You have syntax error in the posted code

Comment: @ButiriDan Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: For this function you will want to use a long instead. Factorials cause a overflow crazy fast because the growth is so high.

Comment: this is not really neat way of solving it recursively

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to both use recursion and a for loop. You can solve the problem using either.

Comment: So what should I do instead? Note that I have very little  background and knowledge so I know only the basic things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive solution:

```java
  public static long factorial(long n) {
    if(n == 0 || n == 1) {
      System.out.print(1 + " ");
      return 1;
    }

    long result = n * factorial(n - 1);
    System.out.print(result + " ");
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but I did not learn what is "long" yet, I am just starting and the exercise should use only basic things

Comment: `long` is a numeric type that stores more bits than `int` before overflowing. They are completely interchangeable in this case, provided n! < 2 147 483 647

Comment: `long` is just a primitive data type like `int` that can store larger numbers. Using an `int` for factorials can cause integer overflows very quickly. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion

```
int temp = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    temp *= i;
}
System.out.println(temp);
```

The recursion is your loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(print(10));
}

public static long print(long n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * print(n - 1);
}
```

Output

```
3628800
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear in the question, but I believe the purpose is to print n _factorial_, not literally print `n!`

Comment: That is now how I understood the question, I think we need to print the value and not k!

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote works, however you are recalculating a bunch of stuff, and you're still using a `for` loop when you could do this entire thing recursively and with less code.

Assuming you are stuck using the function `Print(int n)`, you can write less code and only calculate each factorial once by recursing upwards from `1` and carry the calculations with it:

```
public static void Print(int n) {
    PrintHelper(1, n, 1);
}

private static void PrintHelper(int i, int n, long factorial) {
    if (i > n)
        return;

    factorial *= i;
    System.out.println(factorial);
    PrintHelper(i + 1, n, factorial);
}
```

This is easier to read, easier to reason about, and avoids doing the same calculations over and over again.

In the example I posted above, I am doing `n` multiplications. In your example you are doing approximately `n^2 / 2` multiplications since you iterating over every number again and again (ex: 1*2*3*...*50, then 1*2*3*...*49, then 1*2*3*...*48, ...etc).

The code I wrote omits error checking for brevity of demonstration, since you can trivially add input sanity checks to it.

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner will look like:

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    return (n <= 2) ? n : n * factorial((n-1));
}
```

The [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java) folds the if-statement. Then using recursion, each function call becomes a factor in the factorial function, until the base case (`n <= 2`) is reached:

> 4 * factorial(3)
>
> > 4 * 3 * factorial(2)
> >
> > > 4 * 3 * 2

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion to get the factorial of a number (previous exercise), this method will look something like

```
long factorial(long n) {
    if (n > 0) {
        return n*factorial(n - 1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Given this, it's better to not use recursion and just use a loop to get the factorial of a number, like so:

```
long factorial(long n) {
    long factorial = 1;
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorial *= i;
    }
    return factorial;
}
```

if you want all numbers in the series

```
long[] factorials(long n) {
    long[] factorials = new long[n+1];
    long factorial = 1;
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorial *= i;
        factorials[n] = factorial;
    }
    factorials[0] = 1;
    return factorials;
}
```

If you only need to print them, the method becomes

```
void factorials(long n) {
    long factorial = 1;
    System.out.println(factorial); // 0!
    for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        factorial *= i;
        System.out.println(factorial);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This adds printing in a way that doesn't make the recursive expression harder to read.

```
public class Fact {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        fact(5L);
        System.out.println();
    }

    static long fact(long n) {
        return print(
            n == 0 || n == 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1));
    }

    static long print(long i) {
        System.out.print(Long.toString(i));
        return i;
    }
}
```