# Ternary return in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code from JavaScript

```
function getURL(a, b) {
    return ++b ? String.fromCharCode((a = a.charCodeAt() + 47, a > 126 ? a - 94 : a)) : decodeURIComponent(a).replace(/[^ ]/g, this.getURL);
}
```

A is an encoded URL so a String, B isn't even necessary to pass in, but it can be any String.

And I have to port it over to Java for Android Development. I just don't quite get how the ternary works with the return in this function.
I thought the ternary means if(before?) {Stuff before colon} else {Stuff after colon}, but I don't understand how that works in combination with the return. If I understand that it shouldn't be hard to port it to Java

Comment: It works the same in Java and javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary Operator - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java)

Comment: But how does the return work with a ternary?

Comment: The expression on the right hand side of `return` (in this case the ternary expression with another, nested, ternary expression) is evaluated first; and the result is returned.

Comment: `return` returns a value. In `return 2 + 2;`, `2 + 2` is an expression, i.e. it evaluates to a value. In `return condition ? trueValue : falseValue;`, `condition ? trueValue : falseValue` is an expression. `+` is an operator. `?:` is an operator.

Comment: Ok thank you. I got it now.I think it would be easier if you imagine brackets around everything after the return. But that solves it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so everything after the **return** is as if it were in brackets. This is solved now.