# Ternary operator syntax (Java)

Tags: java

The are several subjects on `Ternary Operator` as here:

[Ternary Operator - JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java)

Except that, I don't understand the syntax.

I have a method with an `if` and an `else`.

```
public static void affichage(String[] tabPersonnage, int[] tabAge, boolean[] tabSexe){

    for(int i=0; i<tabPersonnage.length; i++){
      System.out.println("Personnage n° " + (i+1));
      System.out.println("Pseudo : " + tabPersonnage[i]);
      System.out.println("Age : " +  tabAge[i] + " ");
      if(tabSexe[i]){
        System.out.println("Sexe : Homme ");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Sexe : Femme ");
      }
      System.out.println("-------------------");
    }

  }
```

The syntax for the ternary operator is

```
condition ? instruction1 : instruction2
```

I tried this:

```
public static void affichage(String[] tabPersonnage, int[] tabAge, boolean[] tabSexe){

    for(int i=0; i<tabPersonnage.length; i++){
      System.out.println("Personnage n° " + (i+1));
      System.out.println("Pseudo : " + tabPersonnage[i]);
      System.out.println("Age : " +  tabAge[i] + " ");
      System.out.println("Sexe : " + ((tabSexe[i])  ? "Homme": "Femme")));
      System.out.println("-------------------");
    }

  }
```

I have an error message => `error: ';' expected`

Comment: Typo. One too many `)`. It should be `System.out.println("Sexe : " + ((tabSexe[i]) ? "Homme" : "Femme"));`

Comment: That's because you have unbalanced parentheses. It's not specific to the conditional operator  ("the ternary operator" is a bad name, it just means "the operator with 3 operands")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```java
System.out.println("Sexe : " + ((tabSexe[i])  ? "Homme": "Femme")));
```

to

```java
System.out.println("Sexe : " + (tabSexe[i] ? "Homme": "Femme"));
```