# What does "(o==null ? a==null : o.equals(a))" mean in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

What does "(o==null ? a==null : o.equals(a))" mean in Java? I'm reading this from the "contains" method documentation of an ArrayList.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator

Comment: actually it is `nullsafe equals`

Answer (score 1):

It's [ternary comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163713/ternary-operator-java), and is equivalent to the following if statement:

```java
if (o == null)
a == null;
else
o.equals(a);
```

Comment: Yes and no. It's more like: "The value of `x` given `if (o == null) x = (a == null); else x = o.equals(a);`"

Comment: I don't see ``x`` anywhere in the question though.

Comment: @Leaderboard that is the point, just `(o==null ? a==null : o.equals(a))` does not mean / do anything, it is either accompanied by an `something = ...` or `return ...`.

Comment: @Leaderboard I mean that `(o==null ? a==null : o.equals(a))` actually evaluates to something. Your code doesn't.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't; I was just converting the exact text the OP wrote. Aware in practice that's set to some variable (x in Federico's comment).